# Acceptance testing an incrementing value

Tags: java, junit, acceptance-testing

I have a service which returns id of the created file, and afterwards it increments the id to identify the next file. For acceptance tests we have different project, therefore when I run the test it only passes if it is the first time this service is called. Is there any workaround I can use to overcome this issue?

```
@Test
public void createFileServiceTest(){
    int id = service.createFile("test.xml");

    assertEquals(0, id);
}
```

Comment: You need to reset the counter which must be `0` for your test to pass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your test does not match your specification/verbal explanation of the service. So you should not look for a workaround but cleanly redesign the test (or the service, or both).

### Redesigning the test, for instance

```
@Test
public void creatingAFileTwiceShouldYieldDifferentIDs(){
    int id1 = service.createFile("test.xml");
    int id2 = service.createFile("test.xml");

    assertThat(id1, not(equalTo(id2)));
}

@Test
public void creatingFilesShouldYieldSuccessiveIDs(){
    int id1 = service.createFile("test1.xml");
    int id2 = service.createFile("test2.xml");

    assertThat(id1+1, is(equalTo(id2)));
}
```

### Redesigning both, making the service more testable, for instance

```
@Test
public void resetServiceShouldResetGetMaxId(){
    service.reset();
    assertThat(service.getMaxId(), is(equalTo(0)));
}

@Test
public void getMaxIdShouldYieldLatestId(){
    int id = service.createFile("test.xml");
    int newMaxId = service.getMaxId();

    assertThat(id, is(equalTo(newMaxId)));
}

@Test
public void creatingFilesShouldYieldSuccessiveIDs(){
    int oldMaxId = service.getMaxId();
    int id = service.createFile("test.xml");

    assertThat(oldMaxId+1, is(equalTo(id)));
}
```

Of course, if you have concurrent access to the service, you should guarantee atomicity of your tests, or weaken your checks from `(a+1==b)` to `(a<b)`.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood you correctly, may be try to check it this way:

```
@Test
public void createFileServiceTest(){
    Integer id = service.createFile("test.xml");

    assertNotNull(id);
    assertTrue(id > 0);

    Integer id2 = service.createFile("test2.xml");
    assertNotNull(id2);
    assertTrue(id2 > 0);

    assertTrue(id2 > id);
}
```